# Preventing circular JSON conversions on ManyToMany entities

Tags: java, spring, rest, jpa, jackson

I am converting JPA entities to JSON for a REST API.  Several of the entities have `ManyToMany` relationships which can cause recursion in the conversion process. I understand how to use @JsonIgnoreProperties to prevent recursion on the `ManyToOne` relationship, but not `ManyToMany`. Any guidance appreciated.  Here is an example:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.DETACH})
@JoinTable(name = "insurance_companycodes", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "insurance_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "insuranceCompanyCode_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })  
private Set<InsuranceCompanyCode> insuranceCompanyCodes = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: I guess returning entity is not a good option for rest services. Get DTO to controller as body return it as Resource

Comment: I was thinking that.  So a separate DTO class may be preferred?

Comment: You can use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReferenc` which solve your problem.

Comment: @skyman go for DTOs. Jackson-specific annotations on entities will work and may be sufficient for trivial applications that will remain trivial. Otherwise, you mess separation of concerns (entities concern = persistence, DTO concern = transport) and you may accidentally send more data than appropriate when you add fields to the entity.

Comment: Thank you for the comments.  I think its best if I add DTO's